# Next and Previous nav links in same category with post titles

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this working code in a WordPress widget :

```
<div class="portfolio-links" >
<span style="float:left"><?php next_post_link('%link'); ?></span>
<span style="float:right"><?php previous_post_link( '%link'); ?></span>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to limit the links only to the same portfolio category

< [Prev.Cat.Post.Title1](http://#) __________ [Next.Cat.Post.Title2](http://#) >

I tried using `<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', TRUE ); ?>` but I didn't figure out a way to add the post title.

I also tried `<?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?>` but that leaves me with an empty string for some reason.

An alternateve way would be to use a code of the type :

```
if(portofilio_category = 'my-category'){
...
}
```

Only I don't know how to do it.
Both solutions would work for me.

Useful reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The [Wordpress reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) mentions:

> link : Default '%title'.

So this should work for you:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', '%title', TRUE ); ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using this code produces and empty element. There is no link, nor title.